# Width/Height in pixels for far away transformed elements

Tags: javascript, css, transform, pixel, impress.js

I'm currently working on an interface for the web which uses 3D-transforms as a method for zooming. The zooming is done with an API called [impress.js](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/bored) which simply put moves a camera closer or further away with 3D-transforms.

**Problem**

I need to create a square overlay for a bunch of divs and because they can be far away I need to calculate the amount of pixels they actually take up on the screen. I figured that since I can get how many pixels from the div that the camera currently is, I should be able to determine the apparent pixel size of the far away elements.

I have tried estimating it with angular sizes, looking at [here](http://www.1728.org/angsize.htm). However it does not work when you move too close, too far or an object is too thin or wide.

**Code**

What I currently do looks something like this:

```
    var div = $("#target"),
        camera = $("#camera"),

        angularSize = camera.z < 0 ? Math.tan(div.offsetWidth / camera.z) : 1;

    return {
             width: div.offsetWidth * angularSize,
             height: div.offsetHeight * angularSize,
           }
```

But it only works for certain elements, and not perfectly either.

**What I Have:**

- Actual width/height of each element
- The amount of pixels in Z-index that I am looking at my elements from.

**What I need**

- Amount of pixels the far-away elements *actually* take up on my screen.

If someone knows how I can calculate this I would love some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I realised that I overcomplicated things, and could just use the camera's *normal view distance* and its *current position*.

The camera's perspective before any movement was 1000px  and I could get the camera's current z-position any time so I did this:

```
    sizeScale = 1000 / camera.z;
    return {
               width: element.offsetWidth * sizeScale,
               height: element.offsetHeight * sizeScale,
           }
```